# What do with "SIGQUIT" signal when porting to mingw?

Tags: c, mingw, porting

I'm trying to port some C software to win32 but I don't know how to handle the SIGQUIT signal. I checked the signal.h of Mingw and it doesn't support SIGQUIT (or SIGHUP for that matter, but I'm assuming I can just ignore that one).

It comes up multiple times, here is one example:

```
switch (sig) {
     case SIGHUP:
     case SIGINT:
     case SIGTERM:
     case SIGQUIT: {
         /*
         // Bunch of code here removed
         */
         exit(0);
         break;
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows does only support [a small range of signals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `SIGQUIT` is not supported. mingw just took the definitions from Microsoft.

I'd just check if it was defined before using it:

```
switch (sig) {
     case SIGINT:
     case SIGTERM:
#ifdef SIGHUP
     case SIGHUP:
#endif
#ifdef SIGQUIT
     case SIGQUIT:
#endif
     {
         /* ... */
     }
}
```

Or course, you could also check for `_WIN32`, which is always defined in common windows preprocessors, or `__MINGW32__`, which is always defined when using a mingw preprocessor.
Don't get confused by the "32" in those names: Both will also be defined when compiling for 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I realize I can just ignore it, but what bothers me is that the SIGQUIT case is the only one with code _and_ it ends with an exit(). Is it safe to assume that I can just ignore it? Would be logical at all to move the SIGQUIT code to another case, like SIGTERM?

Comment: Well, that would definitely depend on your code and program logic... It might be logical in your application to map it to either SIGINT or SIGTERM (or even SIGHUP, don't know your code ;)

Comment: The thing is it's not even my code! Haha, thanks though I'll fiddle around with it and see what I can do.

Comment: @Nate Even if it is a bit late: C switch-cases fall through to the next one unless they hit a break, so it is common to put multiple cases before some code to have all of them run it. You could 'safely' remove the `case SIGQUIT` line, but not the code afterward. The braces aren't necessary either, but they allow defining variables local to just that case.